# Read and Append List From Multiple Files

Tags: python, list

Say I have 3 files as shown below. mylist.py consists of a list and function to append to the list. main.py gets a value for variable 'x' from an input and passes it to the addList function in mylist.py. And theoretically I would like main2.py to just print out the global_list from mylist.py containing the value for x I just inputted in main. Obviously it doesn't work like this and when I add a value to the list through main.py and then run main2.py it will print an empty list. I was wondering how I could tackle this concept where I can add to and get the values in the list across 2 or more files? Thanks!

mylist.py:

```
global_list = []

def addList(x):
    global_list.append(x)
```

main.py:

```
import mylist

x = input("value:")

mylist.addList(x)
```

main2.py:

```
import mylist

print(list.global_list)
```

Comment: If you need data to be visible to different script invocations, you need to save it in a file or database.

Comment: @Barmar hmm okay. How would I implement this using this sort of example?

Comment: There are many tutorials on reading and writing files from Python, I wouldn't want to step on their toes.

Comment: Use json or pickle to save structured data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because these are separate files, and therefore will be run as multiple Python processes, there is no practical way to make data in variables persist between all of them. To do this, it's most practical to use persistent storage such as a file.

Here's a simple example, where we'll use a text file that delimits each item with a space to represent the persistent list:

mylist.py:

```
data_file = "./mylist.txt"
delimiter = " "

def get_list():
    with open(data_file, "r") as f:
        data = f.read().split(delimiter)
    return data

def set_list(new_list):
    with open(data_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(delimiter.join(new_list))

def append(val):
    cur_data = get_list()
    cur_data.append(val)
    set_list(cur_data)

# other helper functions
```

main.py:

```
import mylist

x = input("value: ")
mylist.append(x)
```

main2.py:

```
import mylist

print(mylist.get_list())
```